# What kind of lawyer should I contact after not receiving the service which I paid for?

Tags: lawyer, customer-service, postal-service, threats

I went to a courier company to pick up my package and not only was my package not released (in spite of me having all the legal documents) when I pressed for an explanation I was asked to leave the store or threatened that the police would be called. I did not threaten or raise my voice (all of this is recorded in the store camera). I want to appoint a lawyer to speak on my behalf. What kind of lawyer should I be contacting?

Comment: next time instead of "asking for an explanation" instead ask what do you need to do to get the package.  This is interpersonal not legal advice.

Answer (score 1):

The OP did not specify the jurisdiction. It may well be a crime for a *postal service* (and some courier companies qualify as such, in some jurisdictions) to fail to release a parcel to the lawful recipient. That would be a case for the prosecutor's office. In other jurisdictions, a civil matter depending on who owns the parcel at this point -- the sender or the recipient?

On the other hand, there are usually two sides to such a story. I find it implausible that the courier staff would simply say "no" with no reason. More likely something happened **in the eyes of the courier staff** which prompted them to act like they did. They are in the business of delivering parcels, not in the business of frustrating customers.

A customer arguing a point repeatedly in a stressful situation may well appear considerably more threatening to the staff than the customer perceives himself or herself to be. The customer might think of it as being "firm and non-threatening" without raising a voice, the staff might think of it as being "unreasonable and intruding into their personal space."

Comment: It was FedEx. Actually she called to apologize and admitted it was her fault and I have accepted her apology and brought the matter to an closure.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to claim damages for not receiving the parcel then you can probably sue them in the small claims court, or whatever your local version of that is. No lawyer required.

Hiring a lawyer will almost certainly cost far more than any damages. That's why small claims procedures exist: to deal with such things quickly and cheaply.

You don't say where you are, but start by googling "{your jurisdiction} small claims".

Comment: Sometimes the content of a parcel is not easily replacable by it's monetary value. I had shipments of things of basically no more monetary value than a few dollars, but I had had waiting times for those of over 6 months. I would have gladly payed a lawyer if they got stuck with a freaking courier service for no reason, instead of getting 4 bucks from small claims and going through the 6 months waiting period again to get new ones. Only to have them shipped to me by the same provider again...

Comment: That's not going to be recoverable, lawyer or not. You might have a better claim against the vendor, as its their responsibility to get the goods to you. But again, its just going to be the value, not any consequential loss (unless you have a contract saying otherwise,  which is unlikely).

Answer (score -2):

### None

The law doesn’t protect you from “bad service experiences”.

Comment: Can I not claim damages for not receiving the service which I paid for?

Comment: If they breached the contract and subject to any valid limitation of liability clause and if you actually suffered damage, yes.

Comment: This comment seems to suggest that the answer is incorrect.

Comment: The question is missing many details that a lawyer could help clear up for the OP, but a flat out "None" is wrong for many parameters of this question.